# Substracting two cells in Excel and dividing by the other one

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have my data in A and B cells. Let A_i be the i-th entry in the A columns and the same for B_i. My formula for column C would be (A_(i+1) - A_i)/(B_(i+1)-B(i)). For example 6th entry would be (A7-A6)/(B7-B6) etc. How can I do that in Excel? I have over 1000 entries so doing that without some automation is nearly impossible.

Comment: Have you tried entering `=(A3-A2)/(B3-B2)` in C2 and filling it down?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Make that an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a concept called "referencing". If you use the address of another cell in a formula, that is called a "cell reference". For example, the formula `=A1` has a cell reference to cell A1.

When that formula is copied, several things can happen:

- copy down one row and the formula will adjust to `=A2`
- copy across one column and the formula will adjust to `=B1`

The cell reference is "relative" and the row number and column letter adjust when the formula is copied. That can be useful when you have data in rows and want to apply the same calculation to each row.

Your notation `(A_(i+1) - A_i)/(B_(i+1)-B(i))` uses `i` to denote the current row. If you write the formula in row 1, then `i=1` and the formula would look like

```
=(A2 - A1)/(B2 - B1)
```

Following the nature of relative referencing, all you need to do is copy the formula down. In each row, the relative row numbers will be adjusted accordingly.

I some scenarios you want to avoid that adjustment. For example if you have a sales tax rate in A1 and you want to calculate the tax for all rows from row 2 to 100. The Sales amount is in column B and the first data is in row 2. Your formula would start in row 2. In order to keep the `1` in `A1` fixed, you would use a $ sign in front of the row number.

```
=B2*A$1
```

Copy one row down and it becomes

```
=B3*A$1
```

See how the relative row reference changes from `B2` to `B3`, but the absolute row reference stays the same.

The $ sign can be in front of the row number, the column letter, both, or none. A true absolute cell reference has $ in front of both row number and column letter. The different behaviours can be seen in this example

[image]